# Java Pentaho 3.7 get all the subreports

Tags: java, sql, pentaho, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to create a report with pentaho 3.7 based on an as400 server(using sql). I have already defined my report like this
Query 1 SELECT FIELD A, FIELD B FROM FILE WHERE .... for the report's header;
(Subreport n. 1) Query 2 SELECT ..... FROM FILEB WHERE....
And then, for each row fetched by the query 2 an other query 3 wich returns other rows in Subreport n.2

Query 1;

Query 2 row1
        Query 3 row 1,2,3,4...;
Query 2 row2
        Query 3 row 1,2,3,4...;

I need to get all the queries from all the subreports(headers too)
How can I retrieve them?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "get all the queries"? Why do you need them? In what form do you expect to get queries?

Comment: What columns in Query2 will you use to identify rows in Query3 that you want? The two queries need some matching data values for SQL to know what data to get.